# How to hide a TabLayout with BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I have a `TabLayout` with 3 tabs and a `BottonNavigation` and I need that at the moment of pressing patients and configuration the `tablayout` disappears, I do not know what line of code I need?
I also use a `ViewPager`, everything works well the only thing I need is that the `TabLayout` disappears when it is in patients. In the Patient Fragment I will use a `recycleView` and `CardView`, I want to show the photo of the patient and his data

project image:

[image]

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView mbottomNavigation;
private ViewPager mviewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //bottomNavigation
    mbottomNavigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    mbottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    //aqui se especifica donde es que se quiere que inicie el bottom
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AgendaFragment()).commit();
    //ViewPager
    mviewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(mviewPager);
    final BottomNavigationView navigation=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);
    mviewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_agenda);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_pacientes);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_configuracion);
                    break;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}

private OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = new OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_agenda:
                mviewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_pacientes:
                mviewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                return true;
            case R.id.nav_configuracion:
                mviewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager mviewPager) {
   BottomNavPagerAdapter adapter=new BottomNavPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
   adapter.addFragment(new AgendaFragment());
   adapter.addFragment(new PacientesFragment());
   adapter.addFragment(new ConfiguracionFragment());
   mviewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


}
```

PatientsFragment.java:

```
public class AgendaFragment<toolbar> extends Fragment {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager firstViewPager;


public AgendaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_agenda,container,false);
    firstViewPager=(ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_content);
    tabLayout=(TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(firstViewPager);
    setupViewPager(firstViewPager);
    return rootView;
}


private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    TabViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Today");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Tomorrow");
    adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "Other Date");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Comment: If you do not want tabs in `PacientesFragment` and `ConfiguracionFragment`, simply call `tabLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`  or `tabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);` in their respective code.

Answer (score 0):

You could just keep your activity layout with the BottomNavigation and the FrameLayout to show the content of each navigation item. Add the AppBar with the Toolbar and TabBar in your Agenda Fragment layout.